# State pattern - c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, state-pattern

Im trying to implement a Finite State Machine with the State Design Pattern, im very new to c++ and a beginner programmer in general. includes and header files confuse me and I'm not quite sure how to correctly set up this project. I probably should start with something else but I don't really have a choice.

The goal for the machine is to read a char and, depending on the State, do something different.

This is the class layout i thought of:

```
Machine.h

class Machine{
   void setCurrentState(State s);
   State currentState;
}

State.h

class State{
   virtual void read(char c, Machine* m) = 0;
}

(Should i make a header file for each derived class?)

Initial.h

class Initial: public State{
   void read(char c, Machine* m){
      m->setCurrentState(new SomeState());
   }
}
```

I tried to do it that way but I'm confused on what I should include where. I'm getting, depending on which way I do it wrong errors from type not defined to undefined reference vtable. Maybe you guys could help me set this up correct and get the linking on point, id appreciate it a lot.

Comment: `State currentState;` should be `State* currentState;`.

Comment: In general, use one pair of h/cpp per class, and make all variables private by default. Also, if you want pointers to other classes, use a std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr for automatic resource management. Sometimes, you need std::weak_ptr too.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Usually for `State` you're well off with a raw or `std::weak_ptr`, since those classes should provide just different behavior, but shouldn't hold data themselves.

Comment: Yes, weak_ptr is also good for breaking loops, so you do not get memory leaks.

Comment: Also I think it is worth mentioning, that this looks like "classic OOP" approach. Maybe it is easier to start a bit more functional and then refine from there: ``using State = uint8_t;  struct Result { char output; State state }; Result myStateMachine( State state, char input) { switch(state) { ... } ...}``

Answer (score -2):

You can use C guards. That means you declare some variable in every header file.

```
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H
your header
#endif
```

Now everything between #ifndef and #endif would'n be included twice and ld would'n return error.

In every source file you just include what the source need.

Comment: The OP will have to solve the problem of circular dependencies and using a forward declaration as well.